# How to decrypt a bitcoin.com json AES wallet backup?

Tags: bitcoin

Given you have a bitcoin wallet.json backup in the following format:

```
{
  "ct" : "xyz",
  "iter" : 10000,
  "adata" : "",
  "salt" : "xyz",
  "cipher" : "aes",
  "ks" : 128,
  "v" : 1,
  "mode" : "ccm",
  "iv" : "xyz",
  "ts" : 64
}
```

where `xyz` are unique values and the wallet is encrypted with a password. What tools can you use to decrypt this wallet format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an old version of the Bitgo NodeJS package to decrypt the wallet:

```
// index.js
var BitGoJS = require('./node_modules/bitgo/src/index.js');
var bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo();

console.log('Decrypting...');
var password = 'passw0rd';
var encryptedWallet = '{"iv":"xyz","v":1,"iter":10000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"xyz","ct":"xyz"}';
var decryptedString = bitgo.decrypt({ password: password, input: encryptedWallet });

console.log('Private key:', decryptedString);
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "Decrypt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bitgo": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

After replacing the `password` and `encryptedWallet` vars with your own values, you can then `npm install` and `npm start` to decrypt the wallet.